# Как сделать солнечный блик на блоке?

Tags: jquery, css-animation, canvas, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Есть необходимость имитировать эффект солнечного блика на блоке!
Как это сделать?

Просто, может, видели где подобное, чтобы посмотреть, или вообще тотуриал есть.
Думаю что-то с градиентом светлого цвета на бекграунде надо делать или канвас, не знаю даже.

Вот такой элемент - [круг](http://jsfiddle.net/pankov/d7gyu1r4/), как на нем сделать солнечный зайчик (типа чтобы промелькнул или как-то так).
В общем, буду раз любой помощь! 
Спасибо!

Comment:  1. Что мешает поставить на фон картинку?
 2. Всё-таки непонятно, чего именно вы хотите добиться. Приведите пример.

Comment: Если бы был пример, я бы уже скопировал c:

Сам не знаю, дизайна нет, а я не особо дизайнер, прост верстаю, нужен "эффект переливания на солнце, как золотая монетка блестит"

Comment: @pankovalxndr, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Может, как-то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/x3Lhsfhb/)?

Или именно блик нужен, а не отсвечивание?

```
.circle:before {
  content: "";
  width: 80%;
  height:55%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
  border-radius:50%; 
  display:block;
}
```